# How can I extract the TOTP secret from an iCloud Keychain?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, password, two-factor-authentication

iOS Passwords application/pane (*since version 15?*) has [2FA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication) codes ([TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_one-time_password)), and here's an example:

[image: iOS Passwords]

Here I'm using Instagram as an example, because one can enable 2FA for his account only via their mobile application and without a chance to use any other password manager but the system one, as you never see the [QR code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) or [TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_one-time_password) secret. At least that was the case for me on iOS.

How can I now extract the TOTP secret of that code (*a value in the format like `DKFUOLOFUJTDWKIEIS2LZRWGUFZOOAW9`*), so it could be stored in other password managers, such as [KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org), [Google Authenticator](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/google-authenticator/id388497605), [Microsoft Authenticator](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-authenticator/id983156458), etc.?

I can also see the code in the Passwords tab in Safari on Mac OS, so at least it is synced there, and my iPhone isn't the only place where I have it:

[image: Mac OS Passwords]

And theoretically it should be easier to perform the extraction on Mac OS, as, unlike iOS, there is a proper access to the filesystem.

Is there a mechanism to get these secrets back out (*iOS or Mac OS or web*) as plain text after ingesting them to the iCloud Keychain?

Answer (score 8):

Oh well, just before submitting the question, I remembered that Safari supports [exporting passwords](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/438396/92892) to a plain-text CSV file. So I did `File → Export → Passwords...`, and the TOTP secret was present in the resulting `Passwords.csv`:

```
www.instagram.com (USERNAME),https://www.instagram.com/,USERNAME,PASSWORD,,otpauth://totp/Instagram:USERNAME?secret=DKFUOLOFUJTDWKIEIS2LZRWGUFZOOAW9&issuer=Instagram
```

And I've successfully added it to another password manager.

Comment: Did you just put your TOTP-secret in plain text visible for everyone to see?

Comment: I sure did, you can now go ahead and use it, I absolutely allow that.

Comment: i just wanted to point out that if this is your actual instagram TOTP secret, your just undermined the 2FA security of your account

Comment: I'd reckon that goes without saying, it's hard to imagine a person with such a task at hand who would not have a clue about what this secret is for and whether he should share it with anyone but himself.

Comment: I’ve seen people post pictures of their amazon gift cards and similar stuff… better safe than sorry. I’d rather take the risk to point out something obvious than having this person uninformed about the consequences of their actions